# Change the default role when using 'psql'

Tags: postgresql

Whenever I write `psql` in the cmd, it automatically asks the password for a user name 'Master'.
Now, I don't have a user named that way so I don't have a password for it.
I don't see it happening anywhere else.
What I do want is, whenever I write `psql`, it will use the 'postgres' user instead of the non-existing 'Master' one.
Also, I see people in tutorials just writing `psql` and it doesn't ask them for the password. So, I would like to do that as well.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify the user when connecting: `psql -U your_user_name` or set an [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

Comment: Read documentation here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) under section 'Connecting to a Database'.

Comment: postgres is already specified in the pg_env.bat as the PGUSER
```
pg_env.bat
@ECHO OFF
REM The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL

@SET PATH="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin";%PATH%
@SET PGDATA=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data
@SET PGDATABASE=postgres
@SET PGUSER=postgres
@SET PGPORT=5432
@SET PGLOCALEDIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\share\locale
```
@a_horse_with_no_name